# Using strtok to parse the string into words

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
        char str[] = "This is a sample string";
        char *pch;
        char piece1[10] = " ";
        char piece2[10] = " ";

        printf("\n %s \n",str);
        pch = strtok(str," ");
        strcpy(piece1,pch);
        printf("\n piece1 : %s \n",piece1);
        while(pch != NULL){
                printf("\n %s \n",pch);
                pch = strtok(NULL," ");
                if(pch != NULL){
                        strcpy(piece2,pch);
                        printf("\n piece2 : %s \n",piece2);
                }
        }
        printf("\n str: %s \n",str); //prints only "This" and not the original string
        return 0;
}
```

I could not understand the second `strtok` called with NULL as 1st argument. When `strtok` is called with the str it splits the first word. what does the `strtok(NULL," ")` , do on NULL?

When I printer str, it prints the first word and not the original string it contained before tokenising.

Comment: "man strtok". Man pages are your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what `strtok` does behind the scenes is put `\0` wherever the delimiter character is found. This is why you pass in `NULL` the subsequent times after the first call to `strtok` (it keeps track of its next starting positional state).

When you print out `str` it is still a pointer to the start of your original string to tokenize but the first delimiter is now a `\0`. `printf` only prints up to a `\0`.

Comment: Thanks for the neat explanantion. If it puts \0 at the end of the string. This\0is\0a\0sample\0string\0. How does it identify the string is ended?

Comment: well, when it places the `\0`s it preserves a set of pointers to the beginnings of all the tokens that are formed as a result. It is this way that it keeps a track of which token you get. so when it runs out of tokens (pointers to beginnings of delimited strings), it knows the strings is done.
in your example case, strtok would keep pointers to T,I,A,S,S and give 'em back to you as you ask (removing them as you do fifo style).

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` changes the input string (which is why you can't use a const/read-only string as input).  Basically, at each break, it replaces the separator with `\0` to terminate it.

It also stores some state globally, which is how it knows where the next item starts.

If you want to know where each word is, you need to keep track of each pointer returned from each `strtok` call.

Comment: Thanks Joe for helping me understand

Answer (score 0):

From man strtok(), see the bold highlight.

The strtok() function is used to isolate sequential tokens in a null-ter-
     minated string, str.  These tokens are separated in the string by at
     least one of the characters in sep.  **The first time that strtok() is
     called, str should be specified; subsequent calls, wishing to obtain fur-
     ther tokens from the same string, should pass a null pointer instead.**
     The separator string, sep, must be supplied each time, and may change
     between calls.

So, it changes the string in place and it keeps a variable between calls.